# Windows 7 pip error after kivy installation

Tags: python, windows, pip, kivy

I used the provided commands on the windows installation section for kivy. Kivy works, at least at the most basic form. It will make the Hello World basic app here, https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html

But when I try to do "python -m pip ###" or "pip ###" where ### is the command (even list) it crashed before executing. When running python from command line the 3 errors are printed at the top, but then python interpreter runs no problem.

This is the output from running a pip command.

```
C:\Users\G@te_Keep3r>pip list
Error processing line 2 of C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.glew-0.1.4-py
2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1
.5-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.12-p
y2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\G@te_Keep3r\.kivy\log
s\kivy_16-04-20_13.txt
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
     exec code in run_globals
   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 217, in main
     return command.main(cmd_args)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 179, in main
     for name in ["pip._vendor", "distlib", "requests", "urllib3"]
   File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 576, in configure
     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
 ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console_errors': 'LogFile' object has
no attribute 'closed'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you have had an old version installed and you didn't remove it before installing a new version, therefore kivy.deps I think(?) crippled your `pip` a little bit. Maybe you forgot you'd installed kivy before?

Remove the version you tried to install if you can through pip, then remove `Kivy 1.8.0` and deps and *then* install a new version. If you don't have anything important in your python, just throw it away and install it from scratch and spare yourself time.

If you have the portable package kivy provided for 1.8.0, you can use [this guide](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#use-development-kivy)

Comment: By deleting the folders:
kivy.deps.glew-0.1.4.dist-info
kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.5.dist-info
kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.12.dist-info

and the files:
kivy.deps.glew-0.1.4-py2.7-nspkg.pth
kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.5-py2.7-nspkg.pth
kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.12-py2.7-nspkg.pth

from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages and python works fine now. I was could not uninstall within pip. I know this was probably not the best way to go about it, but I don't want to put the effort in right now to reinstall all the libs I have installed.